# Excel sheet being used as a searchable database

Tags: database, excel, search, interface

I was wondering if anyone had suggestions on how to go about creating an interface to allow people to search by category and/or name of a company which would then pull up certain records into text boxes on the interface! Any suggestions would be grateful thank you!

Comment: this is a really a `desgin a system for me question` which is a bit out of scope, but see `PivotTables` or `vlookup`, `index/match`, or maybe `SUMIF` depending on your needs

Comment: Is this kind of what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37572688/auto-complete-with-only-text-and-not-numbers-combobox-excel-vba/37620203#37620203 Let me know if this solved your problem.

Comment: Ralph it did answer my question thank you!

Comment: And thank you Scott for your input as well. Pivot Tables were helpful also