# I want to sort a list of strings based on values of adjacent cells excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a list of song titles in one column, and the column next to it contains the number of times that song has been played. I want to order the play count in a separate column and also display the title of the song next to it. Here is what my excel sheet looks like:

```
Title        | Play Count
------------ | -------------
title 1      |  2
title 2      |  1
title 3      |  
title 4      |  3
```

Notice that titles that have not been played yet are blank in the play count column. This is what I want it to look like.

```
Title        | Play Count
------------ | -------------
title 4      |  3
title 1      |  2
title 2      |  1
title 3      |
```

I want this information to show up in new columns so that the original list and play count column remain untouched. So I don't want this done in a pivot table. Preferably it would only return the top 20 or so song titles, but that is not essential. The list is about 250 songs long.

Comment: Copy/paste to new sheet and sort??

Comment: Let us know if this is what you are looking for or if there is anything I might be missing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37239107/sort-range-without-sorting-it-in-a-spreadsheet/37239386#37239386

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim dataCols As Range
    Dim columnsStrng As String

    columnsStrng = "C:D" '<--| change "C:D" with your actual "Title" and  "Play Count" columns indexes (they must be contiguous columns)
    With Worksheets("MySongs") '<--| change "MySongs" with your actual sheet name
        Set dataCols = .Range(columnsStrng).Resize(.Cells(.Rows.Count, .Range(columnsStrng).columns(1).Column).End(xlUp).row)
        With dataCols.Offset(, .UsedRange.columns.Count)
            .Value = dataCols.Value
            .Sort key1:=.columns(2), Header:=xlYes
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```